# PyEphem running error on Ubuntu

Tags: pyephem

I have read previous posts on installation issues. Nothing seems to work.
I have Ubuntu 14.04LTS, 32 bit, Anaconda python ver 2.7.

I installed pyephem using `sudo pip install pyephem` [after checking I have python-dev, and latest pip] Installation said it was successful.

When I run Python 2.7 and try to import ephem, it says Import error:

> No Module named _libastro.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Anaconda and have activated your `conda` environment, you should not need to use `sudo` — that might aim the install at your system Python, the one governed by the root account and by `sudo`, instead. You could try activating your conda environment and then just doing `conda install ephem` because it comes built in to conda, you do not need `pip` plus a compiler to try installing it!

Comment: Thank you Brandon. I uninstalled and installed as suggested. It worked.

Comment: Great! Guess I should promote that comment to an answer so future readers of this question will see it :) Not sure why I wrote it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda and have activated your conda environment, you should not need to use sudo — that might aim the install at your system Python, the one governed by the root account and by sudo, instead. You could try activating your conda environment and then just doing conda install ephem because it comes built in to conda, you do not need pip plus a compiler to try installing it!